# How can I show that this integral is zero?

Tags: integration, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

I am facing the following definite integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau_3 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau_4 \frac{1}{x_1^2+\tau_3^2}\frac{1}{a \tau_3^2+b\tau_4^2+c\tau_3\tau_4+d} \tag{1}$$

with $x_1^2 > 0$, $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are real coefficients and I know (maybe it's useful) that $d$ is positive.

I have no idea how to tackle this integral, but I have put it in Mathematica to see what happens. It gives back $0$ unambiguously if I type it in the following way:

$$\text{Integrate}\left[\frac{1}{x_1^2+\tau_3^2} \frac{1}{a \tau_3^2+b\tau_4^2+c\tau_3\tau_4+d}, \lbrace \tau_3,-\infty,\infty \rbrace,\lbrace \tau_4,-\infty,\infty \rbrace\right]$$

However if I invert the integration measures, it gives me also $0$, but only if some weird condition is fulfilled:

$$\text{Im} \left[\frac{i c x_1 \pm \sqrt{-4bd+4abx_1^2-c^2x_1^2}}{b} \right] > 0\tag{2}$$

The strictly positive sign as well as the $\pm$ make this condition quite selective. For example, for $c=0$ there is no way to fulfill this constraint I think, and this value is not excluded in my situation as far as I can see.

So my questions are:

**1)** Is the above integral $0$ for all values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$? If not, what are the possible results and the associated constraints?

**2)** How can I compute this integral?

Comment: For $a,b,d>0$ and $c=0$, the integrand is positive troughout and hence the integral is definitely positive - no matter how you integrate. In particular, it seems that Mathematica errs in its first output for the special case $c=0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Right, good point. So Mathematica seems to give a special case as a result, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If I delete the term with $c$ in Mathematica and run the integration, I indeed get a non-zero (conditional) expression. Mathematica is not doing a good job here. Any idea how to deal with this integral?

Comment: Okay, looking at this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions), it is clear that I have to know more about the coefficients in order to solve this integral.

Comment: It's not zero. Let $a = 1$. Then $f(\tau_3, \tau_4) = \tau_3^2 + b \tau_4^2 + c \tau_3 \tau_4 + d$ doesn't have real roots iff $d > 0$ and $D = c^2 - 4 b \leq 0$. Under these conditions,
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac {d\tau_4} {f(\tau_3, \tau_4)} =
\frac {2 \pi} {\sqrt {4 b d - D \tau_3^2}}, \\
2 \pi \int_{\mathbb R} \frac {d \tau_3}
 {(\tau_3^2 + x_1^2) \sqrt {4 b d - D \tau_3^2}} =
\frac {4 \pi} {x_1 \sqrt {4 b d + x_1^2 D}}
 \arctan \frac {\sqrt {4 b d + x_1^2 D}} {x_1 \sqrt {-D}},$$
where for $4 b d + x_1^2 D < 0$ we take $\arctan i x = i \operatorname {arctanh} x$.